# Postcondition of a method with mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, post-conditions

I have a mutable object which I populate with data. Once all the mandatory data is present, the object can be “committed”. Attempting to commit an incomplete object raises an exception. Here's a toy example with an object whose `content` is initially `None`, and must be populated with a string before committing.

```
# inline.py
from typing import Optional

class IncompleteFoo(Exception):
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.content = None #type: Optional[str]
    def commit(self) -> str:
        if self.content is None:
            raise IncompleteFoo
        return self.content
```

This code isn't well-structured: there should be a separate method to check completeness. (In my real code, that method would be called in multiple places, because there are several different way to “commit”.)

```
# check.py:14: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[str]", expected "str")
from typing import Optional

class IncompleteFoo(Exception):
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.content = None #type: Optional[str]
    def check_completeness(self) -> None:
        if self.content is None:
            raise IncompleteFoo
    def commit(self) -> str:
        self.check_completeness()
        return self.content
```

I use mypy 0.780 to check types. Understandably, it complains about the code above:

```
check.py:15: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[str]", expected "str")
```

That's fair: in the first “inline” version, mypy is smart enough to know that `self.content` has the type `str` given that it has the type `Optional[str]` and that this part of the code is only reachable if `self.content is None` is false. In the version with a separete `check_completeness` method, mypy does not infer that a postcondition of that method is that `self.content` is not `None`.

**How can I let mypy know that a postcondition of `check_completeness` is `self.content is not None` or `self.content : str`?** To preserve the encapsulation of the completeness check (which is a lot larger in my real code), I don't want to repeat the condition inside `commit`. I wouldd prefer to keep `commit` unmodified from the second version above. I could settle for repeating:

```
# assert.py
from typing import Optional

class IncompleteFoo(Exception):
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.content = None #type: Optional[str]
    def check_completeness(self) -> None:
        if self.content is None:
            raise IncompleteFoo
    def is_complete(self) -> bool:
        return self.content is not None
    def commit(self) -> str:
        self.check_completeness()
        assert self.is_complete()
        return self.content
```

But that doesn't help: mypy doesn't expand the method call to deduce postconditions for the `assert` call.

Comment: The only difference between your two `commit` methods is whether it raises an exception explicitly or allows it to be raised implicitly by not catching a potential exception from `check_completeness`. If you want to assert *statically* that `commit` always returns a string, you have to catch the exception and return *some* string instead.

Comment: The type checker can't make use of dynamic information like "`self.is_complete()` returns `True`". The `assert` statement itself is just a `raise` statement in disguise.

Comment: @chepner I want to assert statically that `commit` always returns a string if it returns. I'm not interested in any static checking of whether it returns. The three versions have the same runtime behavior, but mypy's static analysis gives different results. I'd like to guide mypy so that it effectively recognizes that the two versions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `typing.cast` to tell `mypy` that yes, this value that might have been `None` really won't be `None`. It's little tricky if you don't want to modify `commit`: you'll need a second variable.

```
from typing import Optional, cast

class IncompleteFoo(Exception):
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._content: Optional[str] = None

    def check_completeness(self) -> None:
        if self._content is None:
            raise IncompleteFoo
        self.content: str = cast(str, self._content)

    def commit(self) -> str:
        self.check_completeness()
        return self.content
```

If you are OK tweaking `commit`, you can stick with one variable, and simply call `cast` when you return the value.

```
from typing import Optional, cast

class IncompleteFoo(Exception):
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.content: Optional[str] = None

    def check_completeness(self) -> None:
        if self.content is None:
            raise IncompleteFoo

    def commit(self) -> str:
        self.check_completeness()
        return cast(str, self.content)
```

Comment: The first version still typechecks if the call to `check_completeness` is removed from `commit`, which defeats the purpose of static checking. The second version also defeats the purpose of static checking since it's just telling the typechecker to assume that bad cases won't happen.

Comment: Well, yes, because the things you are trying to encode aren't static concepts. `commit(self) -> str` means that `commit` will return a string, period, not return a string unless it doesn't return at all. `check_completeness` *isn't* a static check; it's a run-time check. Unless some other function gets called and changes the value of `self.content`, `commit` can't *possibly* return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, I know, but I just stumbled upon this question. How about this?

```
from typing import Optional

class IncompleteFoo(Exception):
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.content = None #type: Optional[str]

    def check_completeness(self) -> str:
        content = self.content
        if content is None:
            raise IncompleteFoo
        return content

    def commit(self) -> str:
        return self.check_completeness()
```

MyPy seems happy with this. The following also seems perfectly acceptable:

```
from typing import Optional

class IncompleteFoo(Exception):
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.content = None #type: Optional[str]

    def check_completeness(self) -> str:
        content = self.content
        if content is None:
            raise IncompleteFoo
        return content

    def commit(self) -> str:
        self.content = self.check_completeness()
        # Some more arbitrary code could go here.
        return self.content
```